# Specs with shared_context

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Doing some specs on RSpec 2.99, I am having problems while using shared_context. The following code works:

```
shared_context 'getting a private taxon' do
  subject { create :category, public: false }
end

shared_context 'getting a public taxon with a private parent' do
  let(:parent) { create :category, public: false }
  subject { create :category, public: true, parent: parent }
end

describe 'GET taxons/permalink', type: :feature do
  context 'only_public: true' do
    before(:each) { get taxon_permalink_api_taxons_path(permalink: subject.permalink, only_public: true) }
    include_context 'getting a private taxon' do
      it { expect(response.status).to be 404 }
    end
    include_context 'getting a public taxon with a private parent' do
      it { expect(response.status).to be 404 }
    end
    context 'getting a public taxon' do
      subject { create :category, public: true }
      it { expect(response.status).to be 200 }
    end
  end

  context 'only_public: false' do
    before(:each) { get taxon_permalink_api_taxons_path(permalink: subject.permalink, only_public: false) }
    include_context 'getting a private taxon' do
      it { expect(response.status).to be 200 }
    end
    include_context 'getting a public taxon with a private parent' do
      it { expect(response.status).to be 200 }
    end
    context 'getting a public taxon' do
      subject { create :category, public: true }
      it { expect(response.status).to be 200 }
    end
  end
end
```

However, when I want to refactor the context 'getting a public taxon' to a  shared_context, just like this:

```
shared_context 'getting a private taxon' do
  subject { create :category, public: false }
end

shared_context 'getting a public taxon with a private parent' do
  let(:parent) { create :category, public: false }
  subject { create :category, public: true, parent: parent }
end

shared_context 'getting a public taxon' do
  subject { create :category, public: true }
end

describe 'GET taxons/permalink', type: :feature do
  context 'only_public: true' do
    before(:each) { get taxon_permalink_api_taxons_path(permalink: subject.permalink, only_public: true) }
    include_context 'getting a private taxon' do
      it { expect(response.status).to be 404 }
    end
    include_context 'getting a public taxon with a private parent' do
      it { expect(response.status).to be 404 }
    end
    include_context  'getting a public taxon' do
      it { expect(response.status).to be 200 }
    end
  end

  context 'only_public: false' do
    before(:each) { get taxon_permalink_api_taxons_path(permalink: subject.permalink, only_public: false) }
    include_context 'getting a private taxon' do
      it { expect(response.status).to be 200 }
    end
    include_context 'getting a public taxon with a private parent' do
      it { expect(response.status).to be 200 }
    end
    include_context 'getting a public taxon' do
      it { expect(response.status).to be 200 }
    end
  end
end
```

My specs stop working, it seems like the subject is always wrongly set up.

PD: I don't know if this is the proper way to share the fixture between two specs without repeating code. Any suggestion is accepted.

Comment: Hard to know what's going on... What the hell is `create`? And what exactly does not work™?

Comment: create is a FactoryGirl method
there are no mistakes when creating the objects, my problem is that when I use shared_contexts specs break